# Finding Median of an Array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, median

I am trying to write a C program to find the median of an array, but the task requires to not sort the array. The current code I have works, but fails when there is a repeated number. I am struggling to find a way to account for this case. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int median_finder(int size, int* data) {
    int n1, n2;
    int count = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t < size; t ++) {
    int piv = data[t];
    int higher = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int median;
    
    if (size % 2 != 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (piv < data[j]) {
                higher++;
            } else if (piv > data[j]) {
                lower++;
            } 
        }
        if (higher != 0 && lower == higher) {
            printf("MEDIAN: %d\n", piv);
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        //int num = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (piv < data[j]) {
                higher++;
            } else if (piv > data[j]) {
                lower++;
            } 
        }
        if (higher != 0 && (lower == size/2 || higher == size/2)) {
        
        count++;
        if (count == 1) {
            n1 = piv;
        } if (count == 2) {
            n2 = piv;
        }

        }
    } if (count == 2) {
        if (n1 > n2) {
            median = n2;
        } else {
            median = n1;
        }
        printf("Median: %d\n", median);
        return 0;
    }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    argv++;
    argv++;
    int data[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    median_finder(size, data);
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't  compile are you are missing two closing } in median_finder().  Please update question.

Comment: @AllanWind code has been updated

Comment: Why do you use `float num`?  The result should be an int, right?

Comment: When the size of the array is even, our median is the addition of two numbers, and in many cases this is not an integer and is something for example like 3.5, so thats why I've used float for that case. E.g. array of size 4, arr[4] = {5, 4, 1, 9}, median = (5+4)/2 = 4.5

Comment: That's not the definition of median.  It's the middle of a sorted array, and if the array size is even then it's the lower of the two middle elements.  In your example 4.  It's fine if you want something else, but I suggest you use a different term and you need to define it (like you did above).  Kindly update question.

Comment: @AllanWind code edited to suit the definition of median you have provided

Answer (score 0):

The `median` for an unsorted array with possible duplicate values `a` of length `n` is the element with the value `a[i]` where half of the remaining elements `(n-1)/2` (rounded down) are between less than (`lt`) or less than and equal (`lt` + `eq`) to `a[i]`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int median(size_t n, int *a) {
    assert(n > 0);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        size_t lt = 0;
        size_t eq = 0;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(i == j) continue;
            if(a[j] < a[i]) lt++;
            else if(a[j] == a[i]) eq++;
        }
        if((n-1)/2 >= lt && (n-1)/2 <= lt + eq)
            return a[i];
    }
    assert(!"BUG");
}

// tap-like
void test(size_t test, int got, int expected) {
    printf("%sok %zu\n", got == expected ? "" : "not ", test);
    if(got != expected) {
        printf("  --\n"
               "  got: %d\n"
               "  expected: %d\n"
               "  ...\n", got, expected);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct {
        size_t n;
        int *a;
    } tests[] = {
        {1, (int []) {0}},
        {2, (int []) {0, 1}},
        {3, (int []) {-1, 0, 1}},
        {4, (int []) {-1, 0, 0, 1}},
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; i++) {
        test(i+1, median(tests[i].n, tests[i].a), 0);
    }
}
```